# OpenLayers 3.15.1 - Unable to get value of the property 'add'

Tags: openlayers-3

New error introduced on load of map:

OpenLayers 3.15.1 - Unable to get value of the property 'add'.

Error is in the following line of ol-debug.js:

**this.element.classList.add(ol.css.CLASS_HIDDEN);**

```
/**
   * @private
   * @type {number|undefined}
   */
  this.rotation_ = undefined;

  if (this.autoHide_) {
    this.element.classList.add(ol.css.CLASS_HIDDEN);
  }

};
goog.inherits(ol.control.Rotate, ol.control.Control);
```

Error does not happen in OpenLayers 3.13.0

I am using jquery-1.11.2.min.js

**Update #1**
Issue is only happening on IE9

**Answer:**

OpenLayers 3.14.0 and newer no longer support IE9 out of the box. The last version of out-of-the-box OpenLayers that supports IE9 is v3.13.1. I will be using v3.13.1 for now until all my users are at IE10+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the classList polyfill? According to the release notes for openlayers 3.15:

> As of this release, OpenLayers requires a classList polyfill for IE 9
>   support. See
>   http://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/docs/features#Element_prototype_classList.

More information at https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.15.0

Comment: Seto, you are correct. OpenLayers 3.14.0 and newer no longer support IE9 out of the box. The last version of out-of-the-box OpenLayers that supports IE9 is v3.13.1. I will be using v3.13.1 for now until all my users are at IE10+